# Stream images every sec as a h264 video to vlc from restapi url images

Tags: c++, callback, video-streaming, h.264, gstreamer-1.0

I am looking to stream jpeg images as H264 video in vlc using localhost connection.
The images will be send through by rest api every second need to convert and stream to video url .
I have tried getting sequence image to play from a file with this sample code [Test_launch.c](https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-rtsp-server/blob/master/examples/test-launch.c)
by using the following parse launch

> 'multifilesrc location="/home/Downloads/gen/img.%04d.jpeg" caps="image/jpeg,framerate=8/1" ! jpegdec ! autovideoconvert ! x264enc! rtph264pay name=pay0'

it works fine for seq image but i need to do the same with getting the image dynamically from rest api and trigger to send the image as video through RTSP URL

Is it possible to read and send image dynamically from rest api in buffer format withot saving the image to local disk.
Since i am new to this Gstream concepts if there a sample avaliable it will be more helpfull

Thq in advance . sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You should create on your API a mjpeg Stream if possible then you can read IT with souphttpsrc element. [SoupHttpsrc](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/soup/souphttpsrc.html?gi-language=c)

This is the way we did, maybe this helps u a little Bit.

Br

Comment: if its possible shall i know the full command u have used